# PHP array as array key

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible in php to make an array an array key as well?

Example:

```
array(
   array('sample', 'abc') => 'sample value'
);
```

Comment: no, this is not possible. array keys must be integers or strings. this is explained in http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: You could, theoretically, `serialize()` the array into a string to use as an array key, but I can't see why your design would require this and I don't actually advocate doing it. It would be fraught with problems, like having to reserialize every time you needed to change it.

Comment: not only that it is not possible, but I don't even see a practical use for it - indexes and assoc keys in all programming languages (supporting them) to my knowledge are scalar values

Comment: PHP array keys can be `integer` and `keys` only..

Comment: @IvanHušnjak compound key hashmaps would be one practical use for it. One can use `SplObjectStorage` for that though.

Comment: I'm just absolutely DYING to know why you want to.  Assuming it's not some horribly stray idea, I'm genuinely interested in how this is being used.

Comment: You can have something like this instead: `array( 'sample'=>'abc', 'abc' => 'abc' );`

Comment: @ccKep lua is not part of my knowledge :)

Comment: 4 years ago, I was idiot :)

Comment: 6 years later I admit I was thinking about this. I am passing an array to a complex function which will always return the same results for the same query. So I was thinking (for a few seconds) about caching the query along with its result, checking to see if the query was already performed, and returning the cached result rather than re-calculating work that was already done. There are better ways to do this ... but that's an application that came up. :)

Comment: @TonyG, yeah. I totally agree. At some point, we find ourselves analyzing for wrong solutions and with enough experiences ahead, we then realized how silly that solution before. :-)

Answer (score 13):

No, if you read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys.  This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

And :

> The key can either be an **integer** or a **string**. The value can be of any type.

Answer (score 12):

This is not possible - array keys **must** [be strings or integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

What you could do is use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php):

```
$myArr = array( serialize(array('sample', 'abc')) => 'sample value');
```

Which will be the same as:

```
$myArr = array( 'a:2:{i:0;s:6:"sample";i:1;s:3:"abc";}' => 'sample value');
```

and could be accessed like:

```
echo $myArr[serialize(array('sample', 'abc'))];
```

But note that the serialised string which would be the unique identifier for the array item is clearly fairly complicated and almost impossible to type by hand.

Comment: This is so scary to look at...

Comment: yes.. scary but efficient i think.. thanks..

Comment: Not efficient enough to be the accepted answer? ;)

Answer (score 1):

PHP arrays can contain integer and string keys while since PHP does not distinguish between indexed and associative arrays.
Look for php manual [Php Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score -3):

whats wrong with

```
array(
    'sample value' => array('sample', 'abc')
);
```

you could then do

```
foreach($array as $string => $child){
...
}
```

and use the `$child` for whatever purpose